# How does UTF-8 represent characters?

Tags: utf-8

I'm reading [UTF-8 Encoding](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/utf8.htm), and I don't understand the following sentence.

> For characters equal to or below 2047 (hex 0x07FF), the UTF-8
> representation is spread across two bytes. The first byte will have
> the two high bits set and the third bit clear (i.e. 0xC2 to 0xDF). The
> second byte will have the top bit set and the second bit clear (i.e.
> 0x80 to 0xBF).

If I'm not mistaken, this means UTF-8 requires two bytes to represent 2048 characters. In other words, we need to choose 2048 candidates from 2 to the power of 16 to represent each character.

> For characters equal to or below 2047 (hex 0x07FF), the UTF-8
> representation is spread across two bytes.

What's the big deal about choosing 2048 out of 65,536? However, UTF-8 explicitly sets boundary to each byte.

With following statements, The number of combinations is 30 (0xDF - 0xC2 + 0x01) for first byte, and 64 (0xBF - 0x80 + 0x01) for second byte.

> The first byte will have
> the two high bits set and the third bit clear (i.e. 0xC2 to 0xDF). The
> second byte will have the top bit set and the second bit clear (i.e.
> 0x80 to 0xBF).

How does 1920 numbers (64 times 30) accommodate 2048 combinations?

Comment: Do you use Windows? If so, start the calculator, switch to programmers mode, and look at the binary representations of 0xC2-0xDF, especially the leftmost three bits (in the leftmost four digits, AKA the first byte)

Comment: @KenWhite I know 0xC2- 0XDF is with two high bits set and the third bit clear. My question is: What does this matter with first byte in 2047?

Comment: It's not the *first byte in 2047*. It's for UTF-8 characters that are equal to or below 2047. Values of 2047 or less are represented by two bytes, with the characteristics described for those two bytes.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks. It's very common for non-English native like me struggling lexically

Comment: The quoted text has a surprising omission. It should state: "_For characters `equal to or greater than 128 (hex 0x0080), and` equal to or below 2047 (hex 0x07FF),..._". As shown in Remy Lebeau's answer below, characters with a code point between U+0000 and U+007F only use one byte.

Comment: I can't say I think it does. The question is quite different now from when you received the answers, to the point where it's not entirely clear how the answers answer the question. Also, it seems that there is a fundamental arithmetic error - if the encoding reserves three bits out of the first byte, that leaves five for you, with the ability to represent 32 distinct values (2⁵) and 32 * 64 = 2048.

Comment: @triplee The author clearly defines 0xC2, not 0xC0, as the lowest number, because UTF-8 represents character equal to or below 127 in 1 byte.

Comment: I have updated my answer to try to answer the new question, too. But please don't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of it as a container, where the encoding reserves a few bits for its own synchronization, and you get to use the remaining bits.

So for the range in question, the encoding "template" is

```
110 abcde  10 fghijk
```

(where I have left a single space to mark the boundary between the template and the value from the code point we want to encode, and two spaces between the actual bytes)
and you get to use the 11 bits `abcdefghijk` for the value you actually want to transmit.

So for the code point [U+07EB](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/07eb/index.htm) you get

```
0x07   00000111
0xEB   11101011
```

where the top five zero bits are masked out (remember, we only get 11 -- because the maximum value that the encoding can accommodate in two bytes is 0x07FF. If you have a larger value, the encoding will use a different template, which is three bytes) and so

```
0x07 = _____ 111  (template: _____ abc)
0xEB = 11 101011  (template: de fghijk)

abc de = 111 11 (where the first three come from 0x07, and the next two from 0xEB)
fghijk = 101011 (the remaining bits from 0xEB)
```

yielding the value

```
110 11111  10 101011
```

aka 0xDF 0xAB.

[Wikipedia's article on UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Examples) contains more examples with nicely colored numbers to see what comes from where.

The range 0x00-0x7F, which can be represented in a single byte, contains 128 code points; the two-byte range thus needs to accommodate 1920 = 2048-128 code points.

The raw encoding would allow values in the range 0xC0-0xBF in the first byte, but the values 0xC0 and 0xC1 are not ever needed because those would represent code points which can be represented in a single byte, and thus are invalid as per the encoding spec. In other words, the 0x02 in 0xC2 comes from the fact that at least one bit in the high four bits out of the 11 that this segment of the encoding can represent (one of `abcd`) needs to be a one bit in order for the value to require two bytes.

Answer (score 4):

As you already know, 2047 (0x07FF) contains the raw bits

```
00000111 11111111
```

If you look at the bit distribution chart for [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8):

[image]

You will see that 0x07FF falls in the second line, so it is encoded as 2 bytes using this bit pattern:

```
110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
```

Substitute the raw bits into the `x`s and you get this result:

```
11011111 10111111 (0xDF 0xBF)
```

Which is exactly as the description you quoted says:

> The first byte will have the two high bits set and the third bit clear (**110**11111). The second byte will have the top bit set and the second bit clear (**10**111111).